# CSS vertically centering a section or sidebar

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I'm trying to create a side bar for a page and would like to vertically center a section in another section. The snippet i tried is given below.
I would like the logo section to remain in the center even when the page is resized.
The section containing the logos are in the dashed border. I would like that whole section to be in the center of the sidebar even when resized.

**[Code Snippet Here](http://codepen.io/rbipin/pen/NbLoJE)**

```css
body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}        
.sidebar {
            background-color: gray;
            opacity: 0.5%;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 0px;
            border-top: 0px;
            vertical-align: center;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        .sidebar_logo_sec{
            margin-top:50%;
            padding-top:15px;
            padding-bottom:15px;
            height: 200px;
            width: 100px;
            vertical-align: center;
            text-align: center;
            border:1px dashed black;
        }

        .sidebarLogo {
            height: 52px;
            width: 52px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 2px solid #424242;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="sidebar">
        <article class="sidebar_logo_sec">
            <section>
                <div>
                    <img class="sidebarLogo" src="github.svg" alt="github">
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div><img class="sidebarLogo" src="linkedin.svg" alt="linked in"></div>
            </section>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a perfect [use case for flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/).

If you add these to your sidebar's existing properties:

```
.sidebar {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   // other properties follow
}
```

You should have the dashed section nicely vertically centered.

[Fiddle here](http://codepen.io/andela-iamadi/pen/QGVoEX)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `.sidebar` has fixed position, try removing the `top: 0` and `right: 0` and replace with:

```
.sidebar {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, I will try your approach.